# Adding a model to a Marionette CollectionView's collection doesn't trigger onItemAdd callback

Tags: marionette

So, I'm not sure I quite understand how this callback is supposed to be triggered. If you take a barebones model,collection and views:

```
PatchModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

PatchCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: PatchModel});

PatchView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({template:'#patchview'});

PatchCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  itemView:PatchView
  ,onItemAdded: function(itemView){
    console.log("item was added");
  }
});
```

And instantiate them like this:

```
Patch0 = new PatchModel({});
Patch1 = new PatchModel({});
Patches = new PatchCollection();        

PatchesView = new PatchCollectionView({collection:Patches,el:"dom_id"});    

Patches.add(Patch0);
PatchesView.render();
Patches.add(Patch1);
```

The PatchesView onItemAdded callback never triggers. Hmm...

Comment: Just curious why are you adding empty models?

Comment: I cut out everything that wasn't necessary for the example and made sure it still failed the same way, before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the docs are out of date.  You should use **onAfterItemAdded** or **onBeforeItemAdded**

This was changed in v1.0.0-rc2

> **BREAKING: ** Changed the `item:added` event to `before:item:added` and `after:item:added`

[Link](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/commit/fade8d18d07efa5ac5d32a938f8fd857fedeb06f#src/marionette.collectionview.js)

Here is a fiddle with your example reworked.
http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/axJg4/

```
var PatchCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: PatchView,
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);  
    },
    onAfterItemAdded: function(itemView){
        console.log("item was added");
    },
    onRender: function(){
        console.log("render");   
    }
});
```

Comment: I had the same thought. Looks like Derek already updated the docs but had them clobbered somehow.